# Keras - time per steps increases per epoch. Is there an issue with memory management in my code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[from anaconda prompt, progress bar removed]

```
Epoch 1/200000
250/250  - 15s 61ms/step - loss: 6.6400 -
 val_loss: 1.0008

Epoch 2/200000
250/250  - 43s 173ms/step - loss: 6.6387 - val_loss: 1.0003

Epoch 3/200000
250/250  - 70s 280ms/step - loss: 6.6201 - val_loss: 0.9997

Epoch 4/200000
250/250  - 94s 377ms/step - loss: 6.6736 - val_loss: 0.9991

Epoch 5/200000
250/250 - 123s 491ms/step - loss: 6.6491 - val_loss: 0.9999
```

As you can see, time taken per step increases every epoch. Not sure why this is happening when the model is being fed with same format of data every time.

My Cpu, ram, and Gpu usage are all less than 30% load, but my GPU RAM is always maxed out (7GB)

Below is my keras code.

```
import keras as kr
import h5py as hp
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#generator
def generator(filename, dataset, batch):
    with hp.File(filename) as h:
        d = h[dataset]
        size = d.size
        i = 0
        while i <= np.ceil(size/batch):
            t = d[i:min((i + 1) * batch, size)]
            _price = np.swapaxes(np.array([t['ask'], t['bid'], t['price']]), 0, 1)
            _time = np.swapaxes(np.array([t['year'], t['month'], t['week'], t['date'], t['day'], t['hour'], t['minute'], t['second'], t['microsecond']]), 0, 1)
            _sma = np.swapaxes(np.array([t['sma 1s'], t['sma 5s'], t['sma 13s'], t['sma 34s'], t['sma 1m'], t['sma 5m'], t['sma 15m'], t['sma 1h'], t['sma 4h'], t['sma 12h'], t['sma 1d'], t['sma 10d']]), 0, 1)
            _aa = t['alpha2']
            i += 1
            yield [_price, _time, _sma], _aa
            if i > size/batch:
                i = 0


#inputs
price = kr.layers.Input(batch_shape=(None,3), name='price')
time = kr.layers.Input(batch_shape=(None,9), name='time')
sma = kr.layers.Input(batch_shape=(None,12), name='sma')

La = kr.layers.Dense(6, input_shape = (None, 3), activation='relu')(price)
Lb = kr.layers.Dense(18, input_shape = (None, 9), activation='relu')(time)
Lc = kr.layers.Dense(40, input_shape = (None, 12), activation='relu')(sma)
L = kr.layers.Concatenate()([La, Lb, Lc])
L = kr.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(L)
L = kr.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(L)

paa = kr.layers.Dense(1, activation='softsign')(L)

model = kr.Model(inputs=[price, time, sma], outputs=paa)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
tensorboard = kr.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./TB', histogram_freq = 0, write_graph = True, batch_size = 10)
model.fit_generator(generator('train.h5', 'usdjpy', 512), steps_per_epoch = 250 , epochs = 200000,
        validation_data = generator('test.h5', 'usdjpy', 512), validation_steps = 10, class_weight = {0: 1.5, 1: 110, -1: 110}, callbacks = [tensorboard])

model.save('firstmodel.h5')
```

I am suspicious of some node memory is not being dumped properly somewhere, does anyone have an idea?

-edit

```
del _price
del _time
del _sma
del _aa
```

just tried adding this inside generator loop, does not help

Comment: I cannot find an obvious memory leak, but in you generator you seem to open a .h5 file and use it to generate some data `d`. The while-loop in your generator, however, will never access the opened file again, so you may want to place the while-loop outside of the scope of `with`, allowing the file to be closed when it is not needed anymore and save memory.

Comment: I also cant‘t  find anything but tensorflow will always completely occupy your gpu ram. If you want to avoid this, open up a tensorflow session ( you don‘t have to pass the session because keras will automatically find it) and set the config parameter allow_growth to True. This way only as much gpu memory will be occupied as used.